# Count number of elements with certain properties inside JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have some JSON data:

```
{"humans": [
    { "firstName" : "Paul", "lastName" : "Taylor", "hairs": 2 },
    { "firstName" : "Sharon", "lastName" : "Mohan", "hairs": 3 },
    { "firstName" : "Mohan", "lastName" : "Harris", "hairs": 3 },
    { "firstName" : "Deborah", "lastName" : "Goldman", "hairs": 4 },
    { "firstName" : "Mark", "lastName" : "Young", "hairs": 4 },
    { "firstName" : "Tom", "lastName" : "Perez", "hairs": 4 }
    //and so on...
]}
```

I want to be able to count all people with 2 hairs, 3 hairs etc. Right now I am using `jQuery.each()` plus an incrementing count-array which works fine.
But I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

UPDATE: 
Additional code saying what I am doing right now:

```
var results = eval(data.humans);
var count_array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
$(results).each(function() {
    if (this.hairs == 1) {
        count_array[0]++;
    }
    if (this.hairs == 2) {
        count_array[1]++
    }
    if (this.hairs == 3) {
        count_array[2]++
    }
    if (this.hairs == 4) {
        count_array[3]++
    }
    if (this.hairs == 5) {
        count_array[4]++
    }
    if (this.hairs == 6) {
        count_array[5]++
    }
    if (this.hairs == 7) {
        count_array[6]++
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think there is.... though you may find different versions of the loop like grep etc

Comment: post your actual code to check what you've done

Comment: @ArunPJohny: grep in javascript? I didn't know about it. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Mohit it is there in jQuery same as filter from es5

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`filter` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter an array of objects :

```
var data = {...}

data.humans.filter(function(o) { return o.hairs == 2 }).length
//Return the number of humans who have 2 hairs
```

Take a look [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g5ggfeh/1/)

Answer (score 3):

javascript `for` loop is fastest:

```
var counter = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < data.humans.length; i++) {
   if (data.humans[i].hairs === 2) {
      counter++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution may be what you want

```
var data = {
                "humans": [
                    { "firstName" : "Paul", "lastName" : "Taylor", "hairs": 2 },
                    { "firstName" : "Sharon", "lastName" : "Mohan", "hairs": 3 },
                    { "firstName" : "Mohan", "lastName" : "Harris", "hairs": 3 },
                    { "firstName" : "Deborah", "lastName" : "Goldman", "hairs": 4 },
                    { "firstName" : "Mark", "lastName" : "Young", "hairs": 4 },
                    { "firstName" : "Tom", "lastName" : "Perez", "hairs": 4 },
                    { "firstName" : "Joseph", "lastName" : "Goldman", "hairs": 5 },
                    { "firstName" : "Mary", "lastName" : "White", "hairs": 5 },
                    { "firstName" : "Matthew", "lastName" : "Garcia", "hairs": 5 },
                    { "firstName" : "Patricia", "lastName" : "Allen", "hairs": 5 },
                    { "firstName" : "Larry", "lastName" : "Robinson", "hairs": 6 },
                    { "firstName" : "Manb", "lastName" : "Lopez", "hairs": 6 },
                    { "firstName" : "Jose", "lastName" : "Martinez", "hairs": 6 },
                    { "firstName" : "Deborah", "lastName" : "Walker", "hairs": 6 },
                    { "firstName" : "Joseph", "lastName" : "Lopez", "hairs": 6 },
                    { "firstName" : "Tinman", "lastName" : "Moore", "hairs": 7 },
                    { "firstName" : "Jose", "lastName" : "Jackson", "hairs": 7 },
                    { "firstName" : "Karen", "lastName" : "Goldman", "hairs": 7 },
                    { "firstName" : "Paul", "lastName" : "Taylor", "hairs": 7 },
                    { "firstName" : "Amy", "lastName" : "Gonzalez", "hairs": 7 },
                    { "firstName" : "Richard", "lastName" : "Martinez", "hairs": 7 }
                ]
            };
var counterList = [];
$.each(data.humans,function(i,item){
    counterList.push(item.hairs);
});

$.extend({
    distinct : function(anArray) {
       var result = [];
       $.each(anArray, function(i,v){
           if ($.inArray(v, result) == -1) result.push(v);
       });
       return result;
    }
});

var uniqueCounterList= $.distinct(counterList);
var html = "";
$.each(uniqueCounterList,function(j,itemUnique){
    html += "<div>Hair "+itemUnique+": "+(data.humans.filter(function(o) { return o.hairs == itemUnique }).length)+"</div>";
});
$("#count").html(html);
```

Or http://jsfiddle.net/8g5ggfeh/

Answer (score 1):

here's an example abstracting the grouping function and getting a list style result:

```
var data = {
            "humans": [
                { "firstName" : "Paul", "lastName" : "Taylor", "hairs": 2 },
                { "firstName" : "Sharon", "lastName" : "Mohan", "hairs": 3 },
                { "firstName" : "Mohan", "lastName" : "Harris", "hairs": 3 },
                { "firstName" : "Deborah", "lastName" : "Goldman", "hairs": 4 },
                { "firstName" : "Mark", "lastName" : "Young", "hairs": 4 },
                { "firstName" : "Tom", "lastName" : "Perez", "hairs": 4 },
                { "firstName" : "Joseph", "lastName" : "Goldman", "hairs": 5 },
                { "firstName" : "Mary", "lastName" : "White", "hairs": 5 },
                { "firstName" : "Matthew", "lastName" : "Garcia", "hairs": 5 },
                { "firstName" : "Patricia", "lastName" : "Allen", "hairs": 5 },
                { "firstName" : "Larry", "lastName" : "Robinson", "hairs": 6 },
                { "firstName" : "Manb", "lastName" : "Lopez", "hairs": 6 },
                { "firstName" : "Jose", "lastName" : "Martinez", "hairs": 6 },
                { "firstName" : "Deborah", "lastName" : "Walker", "hairs": 6 },
                { "firstName" : "Joseph", "lastName" : "Lopez", "hairs": 6 },
                { "firstName" : "Tinman", "lastName" : "Moore", "hairs": 7 },
                { "firstName" : "Jose", "lastName" : "Jackson", "hairs": 7 },
                { "firstName" : "Karen", "lastName" : "Goldman", "hairs": 7 },
                { "firstName" : "Paul", "lastName" : "Taylor", "hairs": 7 },
                { "firstName" : "Amy", "lastName" : "Gonzalez", "hairs": 7 },
                { "firstName" : "Richard", "lastName" : "Martinez", "hairs": 7 }
            ]
        };

function groupByHair(array, groupOf) {
 var groups = {};
  array.forEach(function(element) {
  var groupName = groupOf(element);
   if (groupName in groups)
     groups[groupName].push(element);
   else
     groups[groupName] = [element];
  });
  return groups;
}

var byHairs = groupByHair(data.humans , function(h) {
  return h.hairs;
 });

for (var hairs in byHairs) {
 var hairsN = byHairs[hairs].length;
 console.log('in '+ hairs +'hairs-group you have: ' +hairsN+' people');
}
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/0hr0s29n/)**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ? It will group your data and you will get count for same.

```
var groupedData = _.groupBy(YourJsonName, function(d){return d.hairs});
```